# Recovering internal triangles from 3D cloud of points with R geometry package

Tags: r

I have noticed that the *R* package geometry has three functions:

- `delaunayn` which recovers simplices.
- `convhulln` and `surf.tri` recover *surface triangles* but not *internal triangles*

Is there a function in *R* to recover both surface and internal triangles from a 3D cloud of points?

Comment: I am a little unsure, but have a look at the packages `alphashabe3d`

Comment: I tried to google "alphashabe3d R" and nothing came up.  "library(alphashabe3d)" also failed.  "install.packages("alphashabe3d")" resulted in "package ‘alphashabe3d’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)".  Thanks,

Comment: `alphashape3d` typo ... and it had to be in package name...tsts.

Comment: That works.  I'm reading up about it now.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

package `alphashape3d` can do it.